# ER data model (connecting 2 relations)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I just started to take data base managements and I want to know something. Can I make a connection between 2 relations? I mean there wont be any entities or atributes between them. Is it correct If I do this?

Comment: Provide more detail - you're not using the terminology correctly.  Entities in design translate into tables in a physical model; attributes are the columns.  I have no idea what you mean by "making a connection between two relations".

Comment: Well, I have 2 relations and I'm wondering if I can connect them directly or not while I'm designing er model. I just know er model until this time so I don't know what the difficulties can be later

Comment: I have 2 entities and there is a relation between them. I have also another 2 entities and another relation between them. So I want to know if it is possible to connect these two relations between each other or not.

Comment: Update/edit your question with the information.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity... call entities tables so there's no miscommunication.

Comment: It seems to me that you mean "relationship", not "relation".  It so happens that "relation" is actually another word for "entity" or "entity type" - albeit one that nobody uses.  Can you clarify why you want to link two relationships?  If you can describe what you're trying to model, someone may be able to give you a good suggestion as to how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-order to make a connection between two relations (tables) each table must have one or more columns which can somehow relate to the other table.

From the following example we are able to make a relation based on the knowledge we know about animals, even though the two tables have no attributes or entities between them that are the same.

[image]