# Relationship between entity and relation in ER model and relational model?

Tags: model, entity, entity-relationship, relationship, relational

Can I set a relation between an entity and a many to many relationship on ER model? If so, how do you represent it?

I read [ER data model (connecting 2 relations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138227/er-data-model-connecting-2-relations) this but it just speaks about relational model...

In my case I have a supermarkets DB. I will speak just about the entities with this problem:
-*Supermarket* sells *Product*.
-*Product* is sold on *Supermarket*.
-A *Supermarket* sells (0, n) *Product* and a *Product* is sold on (0, n) *Supermarket* : many to many relationship. *price* is a relationship attribute.
-*User* adds a *price* for a *Product* on an specific *Supermarket*.

So can I add a relationship between *User* entity and *sells* relationship? How do you represent it on ER model?

If not I should set a relationship between *Supermarket* and *Price* (in this case as a weak entity: it needs *Supermarket* as identifier) and another relationship between *Price* (weak entity) and *Supermarket* (strong entity).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I have found the solution. There are two choices:
1.- Ternary relationship between *User*, *Supermarket* and *Product*.
2.- Something like in the example in the picture attached:[image]